# Timeline display until the end of the chart

Tags: lightweight-charts

Is there a property to display the values ​​of the timeline to the border of the chart, and not just to the last point?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It might be done in several ways, depending on your needs:

- you can apply one-time content fitting by calling [ITimeScaleApi.fitContent](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/ITimeScaleApi#fitcontent) method
- you can restrict scrolling after the last available point by enabling [fixRightEdge](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/TimeScaleOptions#fixrightedge) option

Comment: I can say that unfortunately both options are not suitable for me. In general, I would like to see the behavior of the chart, as in the "Technical Analysis Charts" library
".
https://trading-terminal.tradingview.com/

Comment: As far as I know there is no behaviour in trading terminal which is not available in lightweight-charts in this matter. Probably you want to change [rightOffset](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/TimeScaleOptions#rightoffset) value then?

Comment: Yes that's right. To be able to scroll the last point at least to the middle of the chart.

Comment: You can do by applying options to time scale or by calling https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/ITimeScaleApi#setvisiblelogicalrange